# What part of the fish causes the hook to catch onto it?

Tags: ninja-fishing

In Ninja Fishing for iOS, what part of the fish causes the hook to catch onto it? It seems to be inconsistent among fish, often causing me to snag a fish I didn't mean to snag.

Comment: I suggest editing the title, as I can see little relation to the actual question.